# Convert inf value from numeric and integer columns into null value in Polars dataframe

Tags: python-polars

I am wondering if there's a way to convert all the 'inf' from numeric or integer columns into 'null'. I wish to do it through column type rather than column name string.

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

df = pl.DataFrame({"label": ["a", "b", "c"],
                "ratio_a": [1.0, 2.0, np.inf],
                "ratio_b": [10.0, np.inf, 20.0],
                "ratio_c": [3.0, 200, 300],
                "ratio_d": [-1.0, -2.0, np.inf],
                })

>>> df
shape: (3, 5)
┌───────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ label ┆ ratio_a ┆ ratio_b ┆ ratio_c ┆ ratio_d │
│ ---   ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ str   ┆ f64     ┆ f64     ┆ f64     ┆ f64     │
╞═══════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ a     ┆ 1.0     ┆ 10.0    ┆ 3.0     ┆ -1.0    │
│ b     ┆ 2.0     ┆ inf     ┆ 200.0   ┆ -2.0    │
│ c     ┆ inf     ┆ 20.0    ┆ 300.0   ┆ inf     │
└───────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying multiple columns by dtype can be done by, for example `pl.col(pl.Float64)`. Recently, this advanced use of `pl.col` was synthesized into its own separate module, [`polars.selectors`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/selectors.html). `cs.numeric()` will take care of all those dtypes in one call for you.

As for replacing infinites with nulls, here's one way with `map_dict`:

```py
df.with_columns(cs.numeric().map_dict({np.inf : None}, default=pl.first()))
```

Another way would be with a `when/then` expression, keeping the original value when it is finite (the default `otherwise` is `null`):

```py
df.with_columns(pl.when(~(cs.numeric().is_infinite())).then(cs.numeric()))
```

(Note the subtlety in the above with the parentheses after the `~` (not negation) - without them, the negation would be done to select every non-numeric column.)

Both of these result in:

```
shape: (3, 5)
┌───────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ label ┆ ratio_a ┆ ratio_b ┆ ratio_c ┆ ratio_d │
│ ---   ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ str   ┆ f64     ┆ f64     ┆ f64     ┆ f64     │
╞═══════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ a     ┆ 1.0     ┆ 10.0    ┆ 3.0     ┆ -1.0    │
│ b     ┆ 2.0     ┆ null    ┆ 200.0   ┆ -2.0    │
│ c     ┆ null    ┆ 20.0    ┆ 300.0   ┆ null    │
└───────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

Comment: The second way works for me and beyond the original dataframe. I have got this error with the first way when applying in a bigger dataframe: `exceptions.ComputeError: TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`.